# How to make vscode act like Visual Studio IDE when pressing Enter within curly braces

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Say I'm writing function:

[image: img1]

after I've pressed 'ENTER':

[image: img2]

after formatting:

[image]

Is it possible after second step (pressing 'ENTER') to get result like in Visual Studio IDE? This result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can download microsoft c# extension in visual studio for formatting c# codes. After download you can write your c# codes, then only right click inside of code file and click **Format document**.

Comment: This is not an answer. I need to format when I press 'ENTER" button

Comment: When writing javascript you can make auto refactoring with     "editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnType": true    configs inside of .vscode/settings.json. But for c#, you can only refactor your code with                                   
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true configs. "editor.formatOnType" config not work with mic. c# extension. So i dont know any way for refactoring while typing on vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting> Automatically format block an } The tick is removed and the arrow is called, then the tick is re-entered.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).